# Geofencing and iOS : Check if we are in a region

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, geofencing, clregion

I'm using the geofencing in iOS 7 and I want to create a method that return true if we are in a specific region (using the identifier). This method returns all regions, not only the region where we are :

```
[locationManager monitoredRegions]
```

Is there a method that return the regions currently detected ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for delegate event, [didEnterRegion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidEnterRegion%3a) and [didExitRegion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidExitRegion%3a), and keep an array/dictionary of active regions. Would be a solution.

Comment: It's a good idea, I've thought about it but I wished that there is a simpler solution ^^. Anyway, I think that's what I'll do for the moment, thanks :)